# How to pass filename via command line when program waits for input

Tags: bash, shell, input, arguments

I have a program which after executed, waits for the user to type in a file name. Is there a way using bash (or any other shell) to pass the file name before executing?
Since it doesn't read argument the '<' is not an option, but maybe there is an easy way to script it? (Running and typing several times becomes boring after a while ;-) )

Comment: pipe and arguments are two different things. have you tried `echo $fliename| yourprogram` ?

Comment: Sorry I've changed it to '<' which was what I meant.

Comment: Nice, that works, thanks. :-) I knew there was an easy solution.

Comment: An even better possibility is to modify your script to accept an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
echo $filename| yourprogram
```

It that doesn't work take a look at [expect](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

this is the test script:

```
$ cat test.sh
read file
echo $file
```

now, a textfile with some path/filename inside:

```
$ cat /tmp/somefile
/var/log/messages
```

now, the magic:

```
./test.sh < /tmp/somefile
/var/log/messages
```

with this, you're telling your script to get the "read" info from the content of a file.